# How does Tomcat know, if an application is OK or NOK?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, tomcat, httpd, heartbeat

Apache webserver is talking to tomcat and putting him into error state, if he isn't reachable ("heartbeat") but also putting him into error state if the application has internal problems.

Problems like a database, which can't be accessable etc.

How does tomcat recognize this? How does the internal check of tomcat look like/work and what is he doing, to decide if the deployed application is OK or NOT OK and communicating this to the apache webserver, to put him out of load?

tia

Comment: "But also putting him into error state if the application has internal problems" Where did you read that? As you say, how would it know? How would anybody except the application know? I suggest you are misinformed.

Comment: this is no misinformation, but a personal sighting. Apache put an application server into error state, although application server was available and running, but the application itself stopped working... and the goal is to find this "How is apache Tomcat checking the application if OK/NOK"